# How to measure page rendering speed continously

Tags: javascript, rendering, monitoring, pagespeed, icinga

How to measure page rendering speed continuously

Hi all

I would like to measure the page rendering speed for a given page.
This should include JavaScript and Ajax Requests.  The measuring should be executed regularly .

I look for something comparable to https://exchange.icinga.com/hggh/check_http_load_time but the plugin looks deprecated and dose not run.
Are there any alternatives with or without Icinga

thanks